# django-filter: how to force use of dropdown?

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter

I'm using django-filter to generate filter options. For some fields that have a foreign key to model with a limited set of options it generates a drop-down menu, but for others it just generates a blank search field. Is there a way to force it to use drop-down menus for all or specific fields?

Here is my code:

```
import django_filters
from app.models import Cars


class CarsFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Recommendation
        fields = ["area", "car_type", "week_num", "released"]
```

Comment: I'm not sure about drop-down, but you could control the filter choices.